# Showing warning post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output

Tags: svn, webhooks

When I am trying to commit to my svn repository, I am getting the error like:

```
warning post-commit hook failed(exit code 255) with no output
```

And I added my post-commit file in **home/repository/pipeline/hooks** directory.

And my post-commit hook file like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`
/usr/bin/wget \
 --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
 --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
 --output-document "-" \
 --timeout=2 \
 http://<jenkins-Ip:port>/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

And my svn installation directory is /usr/bin.

So is this related to this permission type? How can I find the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html), post-commit hook have to exit with 0 status. All non-zero statuses are errors, and your hook (obviously) doesn't work correctly, and because

> anything that the hook printed to stderr will be marshalled back to
>   the client, making it easier to diagnose hook failures

you have to [intercept stderr|stdout output](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#hook-debugging) of wget and check it

Just to note: I suppose, you forgot, that hooks are executed in *empty environment* and plain `svnlook uuid $REPOS` return nothing (svnlook not found without full path to it) and broken path to notifyCommit is generated

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. When I cheked the permission of post-commit file , i found that it owns my machine user - docker. docker is my user of machine. And rest of owner showing the www-data. So what I can do here to change the permissions?

Comment: Jacob - I suppose (blindly) nothing, but check it by inspecting output of script (can it be executed or you'll get error-message about "can't run")